# why under IE7,6  the box above on the border?

Tags: html, css

http://xanlz.com/test/

why under IE7,6 , the box which including the text `"code" "book"` are above on the border? not joining together. the red part in the image
[image]

but ok under firefox.and how to remove the bottom line.when the mouser hover on the text(code or book) and under the default state with text `code`.

the html code:

```
<div class="week-down rounded-corner">
 <h2>week test</h2>
   <div class="ranktitle">
     <ul>
        <li class="tab1 rankactive">code</li>
        <li class="tab2">book</li>
        <div class="clear"></div> 
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="weekrank">
 <div class="code-down tab1" style="display: block;">
 <ul class="item-list itemlist">
 <li><a href="#" >asp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >phpp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >java</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" >asp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >phpp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >java</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >phpp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >java</a></li>

</ul>
 </div>

 <div class="book-down tab2" style="display: none;">
  <ul class="item-list itemlist">
 <li><a href="#" >test</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >phpp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >test</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" >asp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >phpp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >java</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >phpp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >java</a></li>

</ul>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

the main style:

```
     .ranktitle {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .code-down ul.item-list, .book-down ul.item-list {
        border-top: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
        padding-top: 8px;
    }

    #tabs-content ul, ul.item-list {
        padding: 3px 0 0 7px;
    }
.ranktitlewhole ul li.rankactive, .ranktitle ul li.rankactive {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

i use jquery to add a class `rankactive` to the li text. when the mouse on.

Comment: i am sorry. i have updated the question. and got out of the style and html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `<div class="clear"></div>` inside the `<ul>`. This is not valid. Remove it and add to `<ul>` `overflow: hidden;` property.

For IE6 `zoom: 1;` property has to be added. Without this `overflow: hidden;` doesn't work.

And for the second part of the question, try this:

```
li:hover {
   position: relative;
   top: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Let's make it simple.
Remove `overflow: hidden;` and `zoom: 1;` and set to `<ul>` fixed height, for example 15px.
And for li:hover

```
li:hover {
   position: relative;
   top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: i have removed it.it's ok when under IE7,but still wrong when under IE6. ps:do you know how to remove the bottom border when mouser hover on the text. thank you.

Comment: Could you temporarily make :hover styles to a class? In order I can use my firebug.

Comment: i am sorry, i don't know how to do it? i have added these style:.ranktitle ul li:hover,
.weekrank ul li:hover {
   position: relative;
   top: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 1px;
}

Comment: many thanks. it's ok under firefox. IE8,6. BUT not ok under IE7? how to correct it? thank you

Comment: I wrote 15px for example, in your case it's 23px :)